# why my installed beautifulsoup could not be imported?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

i have installed the beautifulsoup4 on pycharm but why the import errors still occur?
[image]

[image: the below pictures are the situation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Be Case sensitive while typing beautifulsoup

It will solve your importing issue if installed correctly

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

All letters in BeautifulSoup should not be small..

Change to,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import `BeautifulSoup` as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

you are trying to import something named `beautifulsoup4` and there is nothing called `beautifulsoup4` in `bs4` module

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a file named bs4? If so, python might be trying to import beautifulSoup from there.

Comment: i think i do but the bs4 is installed with the beautifulsoup4